# How to hide header in CalendarView in DatePicker?

Tags: android, user-interface, datepicker

How can I hide the header on the screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 22):

Use a CalendarView instead. Looks the same as a DatePicker, just does not have a header.

Comment: Please provide more details, such as a code example, for your answer to be more ueseful.

Comment: In your XML, start a <CalenderView /> instead of <DatePicker />.

Answer (score 6):

In order to display DatePicker as calendar view, without a header, you can  switch to spinner mode and hide the spinner, i.e.:

```
<DatePicker
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:datePickerMode="spinner"
   android:spinnersShown="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could not do much about it, what you can do is forced to be a spinner

```
<DatePicker
    ...
    android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Or just create your own custom datePicker
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-datepickerdialog.html

Comment: available in api version 21+

Answer (score 1):

Just use calendar view:

```
<CalendarView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

ou need to get a reference to the LinearLayout of the DatePicker itself and then `.getChildAt(0)` and hide it.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.id.datetime_dialog);
DatePicker datePicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogDatePicker);
LinearLayout datePickerHeader = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);
datePickerHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```